# Laravel 4.2 public_path() differs on Linux

Tags: php, laravel

Using the same Laravel App I get two different results from `public_path()`. Linux: `string(0) ""`, Windows: `string 'C:\xampp\htdocs' (length=15)`. I expect it to be an absolute path on Linux but it obviously isn't.

Comment: `public_path Get the fully qualified path to the public directory.` http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers There seems to be something wrong with your laravel installation on linux.

Comment: I use the same Laravel installation on Linux as I use on Windows. Should I additionaly configure something for Linux?

Comment: @Bright So long as you followed the installation instructions on the Laravel website, `public_path()` should work correctly. If it continues to not work, maybe try using a VM such as Homestead.

Comment: @natzim I've solved the `public_path()` problem by creating a separate sibling `index` file and returning `__DIR__`, what's also weird is that rename works fine but even though it works file it throws a permissions error, I've `caught` the error and ignored it and now everything works fine.